# JCubic Terminal not working on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery-terminal

I downloaded the demo of JCubic Terminal to test on my local PC, but when I open then with my browser they simply display nothing. I tried uploading to my nginx VPS but again, it displayed nothing.

What do I need to do to get output?

Comment: Which demo you're trying to use and does it throw an error?

Comment: Im using the virtual keyboard one.

Comment: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.mousewheel-min.js:2:0
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.terminal-min.js:3:0
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined jquery.keyboard.min.js:6:2
ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: You can try to download jQuery and use it locally, Do you have error while fetching jQuery from google CDN?